# Нині = сьогодні?

Tags: вживання-слів

Часто чую в розмовній мові, особливо старшого покоління слово *"нині"*, і завжди думала, що це застаріле слово або діалектизм і його відповідник - *"сьогодні"*. Нещодавно мені трапилось це слово в значенні *"зараз"*.

В Академічному словнику [вказано](http://sum.in.ua/s/nyni), що слово має значення *"тепер"* або *"сьогодні"*, а на сайті «Студопедія» [вказано](http://studopedia.info/1-41504.html), що також може мати значення *"зараз"*.

То чи правильно вживати це слово? Якщо так, то в якому значенні?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Очевидне (для мене) значення слова «нині»

На мою особисту думку, «нині» — еквівалент до «у наш час».

Тобто йде посилання проміжок часу, що включає поточний момент (часто слово «нині» протиставляють словам «раніше», «колись» і іншим, що зазвичай, навпаки, не включають поточний момент). Зазвичай так кажуть, маючи на увазі доволі широкий проміжок (століття, десятиліття, рік), але коротші проміжки теж можливі.

«Словник української мови» в 11 томах підтверджує таке тлумачення:

> [**НИ́НІ**](http://sum.in.ua/s/nyni), *присл[івник]*.
>
> 1. У наш час, у сучасний період, тепер. *— Во Іудеї не було.. того ніколи, Що нині узриться* (Тарас Шевченко, II, 1953, 310); *Нині світова соціалістична система перетворюються у вирішальний фактор історичного розвитку* (Комуніст України, 4, 1961, 21).
> 2. <…>

## Дивне (для мене) тлумачення слова «нині»

У той же час «Словник української мови» надає ще одне тлумачення, яке особисто в мене викликає подив:

> 2. Те саме, що сьогодні. *Се ж нині був його перший адвокатський виступ у сьому місці* (Іван Франко, VII, 1951, 187); *Нині молодиця закінчила роботу ще до смерку, але їй зовсім не хотілося йти додому* (Михайло Стельмах, I, 1962, 603).

Я особисто не можу уявити контекст, у яких би «нині» означало саме «сьогодні». Навпаки, можу навести приклади, що, на мою думку, показують неможливість використання «нині» у прямому значенні слова «сьогодні»:

- Остап чув, що в його друга Олега на днях буде побачення з Оленою. «Коли в тебе побачення з Оленою» — «Нині».
- Покупець в магазині придирливо оглядає хліб. «Коли цей хліб привезли?» — «Нині».

Для мене особисто в цих випадках слово «нині» аж ніяк не звучить — і не через застарілість чи книжковість слова «нині», а через те, що «нині» особисто для мене позначає проміжок невизначеної довжини, а не конкретно сьогоднішній день. У цих прикладах, якби я почув таку відповідь, я би радше сприйняв «нині» як «зараз»/«щойно»/«от-от», а не як «сьогодні».

І приклади для другого значення зі словника мене не переконують, адже, на мою думку, вони цілком вписуються у значення «невизначеної довжини проміжок часу, що включає поточний момент» і не вимагають окремого тлучачення. Я сприймаю їх більше не як «сьогодні був його перший адвокатський виступ…» і «сьогодні молодиця закінчила роботу ще до смерку…», а як «цього разу був його перший адвокатський виступ…» і «цього разу молодиця закінчила роботу ще до смерку…». Так само вписуються в очевидне для мене значення й приклади з Грінченка.

Але: я обертаюся в певному оточенні, що вживає слова у певних значеннях. І не виключаю, що в інших частинах України або інших соціальних прошарках інший слововжиток. Або що я просто помиляюся.

## «Нині» і «зараз»

Різниця між «зараз» і «нині», по-моєму, полягає в тому, що «зараз» посилається саме на поточний момент часу (або момент часу, що настане дуже скоро, майже відразу за поточним моментом: «зараз прийду»), а «нині» — на проміжок часу невизначеної довжини (часто доволі довгий), що, однак, включає поточний момент.

Відповідно іноді вони взаємозамінні, але зазвичай «зараз» використовують, коли акцентують саме поточний момент (те, що щось відбувається зокрема й у поточний момент, ще не означає, що слухачу/мовцю воно важливе саме стосовно до поточного моменту), а «нині» в сучасному мовленні — коли кажуть про якийсь історичний період, а не про суто поточний момент.

(Також я бачив людей, що стверджували, мовляв, в сучасному мовленні слово «зараз» неправильно вживають, мовляв, насправді «зараз» — це не поточний момент («я зараз снідаю»), а лише момент, що от-от настане («я зараз прийду»), а при посиланні на поточний момент можна вживати лише (!) «тепер» («я тепер снідаю» (?)) — але навіть натяків на підтвердження цього в мовознавців чи літературі не бачив. На мою думку, «тепер» радше виражає контраст із тим, що було, аніж просто посилається на поточний момент.)

Comment: я скажу особисто (родина зі Львова, а жили в діаспорі від 40-х років) що слово «нині» мені значить «сьогодні». Я ще ніколи не чув ужиток як еквівалент «у наш час», тобто було дуже цікаво прочитати — дякую!

Comment: @mancestr, дякую! Тепер я певен, що мені варто уточнити чи переписати відповідь. Бо в чинному формулюванні виходить, що я якось надто категорично висловлююся проти значення «сьогодні» чи принаймні надто сильно в ньому сумнівався. (Хоча підстав для цього нема, навіть словники його наводять.) Спробую незабаром…

Answer (score 3):

Коротка відповідь:

Слово "нині" не дорівнює слову "сьогодні", хоч і має таке значення. При цьому, основне значення слова "нині" - не "сьогодні", а "тепер", "у ці часи", "на сьогоднішній день" тощо.

Додаткові викладки:

По-перше, сайт називається не "Студопед**і**я", а "Студопед**и**я", з такою мовною мішанкою ([перша сторінка](https://studopedia.info/1-41471.html) російською, всі катеґорії також російською, переходжу на ["украинскую версию"](https://studopedia.info/ukr/) - там знову перемішані українська і російська, є взагалі стаття з назвою ["впянанввпвговвяганманная"](https://studopedia.info/ukr/1-56968.html)), яку там бачимо, я би йому просто не довіряв у питаннях, що пов’язані з мовою.

Варто дослідити питання через перевірені словники.

[Грінченко](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%96):

> Нині нар. Сегодня. Бодай мій ворог знав, що нині за день.

Тобто, здається, що на той момент було тільки одне значення, але

[Кримський, Єфремов і ко:](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%96&scope=all&dicts=1&highlight=on)

> 1. тепе́р, тепе́реньки, тепе́речки, сейча́с, ни́ні.
> 2. сього́дні [Хлі́ба на́шого щоде́нного дай нам на сього́дні], ни́ні, ни́ньки, (гал.) днесь, дне́ськи.

Тобто, вже до зближення мов вживається в обох значеннях.

[Академічний словник](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%96) взагалі подає цитату з Шевченка:

> Во Іудеї не було.. того ніколи, Що нині узриться (Тарас Шевченко, II,
>   1953, 310);

в одному значенні слова та з Франка — в іншому:

> Се ж нині був його перший адвокатський виступ у сьому місці (Іван
>   Франко, VII, 1951, 187);

Тобто, слово можна вживати в обох значеннях, воно цілком літературне.

До того ж, на [офіційному сайті української мови](http://ukrainskamova.com/publ/slovnik_sinonimiv/n/nini/36-1-0-10722) є ряд синонімів:

> Синоніми до слова НИНІ: пр. нині тепер, зараз д. ниньки; ЯК ІМ.
>   нинішній день, СУЧАСНІСТЬ; сьогодні.

а також на їхній [головній сторінці](http://ukrainskamova.com/publ/slovnik_sinonimiv/21) пише:

> **Нині** українською мовою в Україні й поза її межами розмовляють близько 45 млн. осіб. За кількістю тих, хто розмовляє нею, українська
>   мова стоїть на 15—20-му місці у світі.